# Bitwise left shift in Python and C#

Tags: c#, python, bit-manipulation

Why bitwise left shift in Python and C# has different values?

Python:

```
    >>> 2466250752<<1
    4932501504L
```

C#:

```
    System.Console.Write((2466250752 << 1).ToString()); // output is 637534208
```

Comment: If you want the similar behavior in C# you'll need to use BigInteger (for any length) or Long (for this case)

Comment: I need similar behavior in Python :)

Comment: Oh, just AND the value right after shifting right with 2^32-1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python makes sure your integers don't overflow, while C# allows for overflow (but throws an exception on overflow in a checked context).  In practice this means you can treat Python integers as having infinite width, while a C# `int` or `uint` is always 4 bytes.

Notice in your Python example that the value "4932501504L" has a trailing L, which means long integer.  Python automatically performs math in long (size-of-available-memory-width, unlike C#'s `long`, which is 8 bytes) integers when overflow would occur in int values.  You can see the rationale behind this idea in [PEP 237](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0237/).

EDIT: To get the Python result in C#, you cannot use a plain `int` or `long` - those types have limited size.  One type whose size is limited only by memory is [BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx).  It will be slower than `int` or `long` for arithmetic, so I wouldn't recommend using it on every application, but it can come in handy.

As an example, you can write almost the same code as in C#, with the same result as in Python:

```
Console.WriteLine(new BigInteger(2466250752) << 1);
// output is 4932501504
```

This works for arbitrary shift sizes.  For instance, you can write

```
Console.WriteLine(new BigInteger(2466250752) << 1000);
// output is 26426089082476043843620786304598663584184261590451906619194221930186703343408641580508146166393907795104656740341094823575842096015719243506448572304002696283531880333455226335616426281383175835559603193956495848019208150304342043576665227249501603863012525070634185841272245152956518296810797380454760948170752
```

Of course, this would overflow a long.

Comment: Thanks, but how I can get on Python the result as on C#?

Comment: @user2160982 Oops, I misread your comment.  Martheen comments correctly on the question: you should take a bitwise and with 2^32 - 1.

Comment: Aah, 'bitwise and', so that's the correct way to describe it. All this time I used AND like some screamer

Answer (score 6):

You are **overflowing** the 32-bit (unsigned) integer in C#.

In python, all integers are arbitrarily-sized. That means the integer will expand to whatever size is required. Note that I added the underscores:

```
>>> a = 2466250752
>>>
>>> hex(a)
'0x9300_0000L'     
>>>
>>> hex(a << 1)
'0x1_2600_0000L'
   ^-------------- Note the additional place
```

---

In C#, `uint` is only 32-bits. When you shift left, you are exceeding the size of the integer, causing overflow.

Before shifting:

[image]

After shifting:

[image]

Notice that `a` does not have the leading `1` that python showed.

---

To get around this limitation for this case, you can use a `ulong` which is 64 bits instead of 32 bits. This will work for values up to 2<sup>64</sup>-1.

Comment: @SnakesandCoffee Ha, oops. Fixed.